# Make sqlite3 column update faster

Tags: python, sqlite

I have written a Python code that iteratively reads data from a sqlite database, does some calculations on it and writes the results back to the database as new columns and so on. However, the part involving writing to the database by updating a column feels to get slower and slower by time. Is there any alternative way that I can do the same thing but faster?

A relevant part of my code is brought below.  In this section of the code, two new columns column_I1_ and column_I2_ are made, each ending by the iteration number, like  column_I1_1, column_I2_1, and then the new results is written into these columns from corresponding lists. The problem is, considering the high number of iterations and the time-consuming nature of calculations, plus high number of rows (here defined by the num value, approximately 11000 rows), this works too slow...

Is there another way of doing this instead of using update? because I think for updating, it has to copy that column each time it adds a new value and this causes the slow down. I used to use Excel for this and was much faster but since there is a 256 column limit for spreadsheet I had to switch to Database.

```
cur.execute("alter table C add column_I1_%d integer"%iter) #makes a new column indexed by iteration number
con.commit()
for e in range(0,num): # num is a given number as input
    cur.execute("UPDATE C SET column_I1_%d=? WHERE Id=%d"%(iter,e+1),(w[e],)) # w is a list containing some results
con.commit()
    #
cur.execute("alter table C add column_I2_%d integer"%iter)  
con.commit()
for f in range(num,(2*num)):         
    cur.execute("UPDATE C SET column_I2_%d=? WHERE Id=%d"%(iter,f-num+1),(w[f],))
con.commit()
```

.....

Your comments are much appreciated. Plus, I am relatively a Python newbie, so please go easy on me! :)

Comment: have you tried `cur.executemany` ? that may be faster...

Comment: @JoranBeasley it is faster, but the difference is very small. I checked, for each update, if in a loop it takes 15 seconds, in excutemany form it takes something like 14.8 seconds. Better than nothing but still too much. And the odd thing is that, as the simulation proceeds and the number of existing columns in the database increases, it slows down a lot. Although it writes same number of rows but in iteration 13 for e.g. same operation takes 1 minute instead of 15 seconds. I yet have not totally understood what to do to reduce the costs...

Comment: Do you have any indexes? Is there some primary key?

Comment: @CL. : no, I dont have primary key, not sure about indexes...here is how I define the table. In first column I define ID just so that later I am able to add elements of next columns in right row (where id=?). Actually, may be I should use without rowid table to make it faster or? As said before, I am quite new to this, so sorry if it makes little sense..                                                     with sqlite3.connect('RDB.db') as con:
    con.text_factory = int
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS C ('id' INT)")

Comment: WITHOUT ROWID makes sense only if your primary key does not fit into an INTEGER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed up lookups on the `Id` column, create an index on it:

```
cur.execute("CREATE INDEX MyLittleIndex ON C(Id)");
```

Alternatively, if the values in the `Id` column are unique, declare this column as the primary key (which automatically creates an index):

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE C(Id PRIMARY KEY)");
```

If the values are integers, declaring this column as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will be a little more efficient:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE C(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");
```

Comment: Wow! This reduced the column writing time by a factor of 10! Thanks! By the way, another question...The time for writing a specific column to the database in each iteration increases, somehow linearly by iteration number. As columns are not overwritten  by me and number of rows is the same, I guess that in each update, python copies and writes the whole database again plus the new values. Is this correct? if so, how can I avoid this?. Also, I tried also to turn pragma synchronous=OFF but didnt make any difference.

Comment: The database needs to update both the table and the index, but these are organized as B-trees; the time needed for that is in O(log n).

Comment: this should make it much faster for alot of things .... you basically always want a primary key of some sort if you can

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to call executemany for one time instead of calling execute in a loop.

For example, consider the code below,

```
for e in range(0,num): # num is a given number as input
    cur.execute("UPDATE C SET column_I1_%d=? WHERE Id=%d"%(iter,e+1),(w[e],))
```

It can be transformed to following,

```
cur.executemany("UPDATE C SET column_I1_%d=? WHERE Id=?"%(iter), zip(w, range(num)))
```

Comment: It made it go faster, though the difference was trivial: t1= 15.3050000668 (s) while t2=14.7929999828 (s). Did we reach the limit?